# Recursively group arrays on multiple keys

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I have an array of objects for example:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 1
            [Name] => Toy Car
            [Category] => Toys
            [Price] => 2.99
            [OnSale] => false
        )
    ...
)
```

But I'd like them to be grouped by Category, then by OnSale.

So far I have been able to group by category using:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($data as $element) {
    $result[$element['Category']][] = $element;
}
```

But I am unsure how to nest another foreach or recursively group them once they have been grouped by Category. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It would help if you mock up an example "end result" array of what you want. Then we could know exactly what you are aiming for and can help better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($data as $element) {
    $result[$element['Category']][$element['OnSale']][] = $element;
}
```

EDIT: Sorry, bit of a problem with all the `[` and `]`...

Comment: Yep this definitely works. Thanks! I feel dumb for not recognizing that! If I were to want to sort on price would I do that inside this `foreach` loop or do that once the `$result` array has been populated?

Comment: It's best to sort on price, within each category, after the array was made.

Answer (score 2):

You're close! You just need to add the second key you want to group by.

```
$byCategoryAndSale = [];
foreach ($inventory as $item) {
    $byCategoryAndSale[$item['Category']][$item['OnSale']][] = $item;
}
```

**Note** Using a boolean value as an array key will equate to 1's and 0's which can get pretty confusing.

Here's a full example:

```
<?php
    $inventory = [
        [
            'Id' => 1,
            'Name' => 'Toy Car',
            'Category' => 'Toys',
            'Price' => 2.99,
            'OnSale' => false
        ],
        [
            'Id' => 2,
            'Name' => 'Another Toy',
            'Category' => 'Toys',
            'Price' => 1.99,
            'OnSale' => false
        ],
        [
            'Id' => 3,
            'Name' => 'Hamburger',
            'Category' => 'Not Toys',
            'Price' => 5.99,
            'OnSale' => false
        ],
        [
            'Id' => 4,
            'Name' => 'Last Toy',
            'Category' => 'Toys',
            'Price' => 50.99,
            'OnSale' => true
        ]
    ];

    $byCategoryAndSale = [];
    foreach ($inventory as $item) {
        $byCategoryAndSale[$item['Category']][$item['OnSale']][] = $item;
    }

    print_r($byCategoryAndSale);
?>
```

Which yields:

```
PS C:\> php test.php

(    
    [Toys] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [Id] => 1
                            [Name] => Toy Car
                            [Category] => Toys
                            [Price] => 2.99
                            [OnSale] =>
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [Id] => 2
                            [Name] => Another Toy
                            [Category] => Toys
                            [Price] => 1.99
                            [OnSale] =>
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [Id] => 4
                            [Name] => Last Toy
                            [Category] => Toys
                            [Price] => 50.99
                            [OnSale] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

    [Not Toys] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [Id] => 3
                            [Name] => Hamburger
                            [Category] => Not Toys
                            [Price] => 5.99
                            [OnSale] =>
                        )

                )

        )

)
```